# VSTO Installable or exe

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-addins

I have created a Excel Add in Application and i have built an .VSTO file out of it.

Now whether i need to create installer for installing it or is there is any we can create .exe file (without installer).

I don't want the installer option as some of the user's will not be having admin access.

So can we create .exe file out of VSTO Excel Add in.

Thanks,
Karthik

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood properly below is the answer....

When do you publish Addin project using right click on project, you can see the *.VSTO file get created on provided path.

That *.vsto file is itself a installer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to "install" an add-in, you require registry entries similar to ours shown below

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins\Chem4Word]
"Description"="Chem4Word"
"FriendlyName"="Chem4Word"
"Manifest"="file:///C:/Dev/Chem4Word/WordAddIn/WordAddIn/bin/Debug/WordAddIn.vsto|vstolocal"
"LoadBehavior"=dword:00000003
```

Simply change the Manifest location is the location where your .vsto and .dll files are.
Also as this example is for our Word Add-in "Word" also needs to be changed to "Excel" where appropriate.